# What's the best way to secure wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

What steps have you taken? Would love to get some useful insight.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress makes a very nice getting started guide over at the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress)

I'll highlight a few I use on all of my sites:

- File permissions

  For Directories

  `find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

  For Files

  `find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
- Move wp-config.php up 1 directory than the default, `chmod 400 wp-config.php`

`<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>`

- Securing wp-includes

  `#Block the include-only files.
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
  RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
  RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
  RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
  RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
  </IfModule>`
- disable file editing in builtin editor `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);` add that to your wp-config.php
- install plugin like [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) to help out with security
- turn automatic updates on
- check and double check file permissions
- if running centos enable selinux and set correct permissions on files and directories
- read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) for a full list of recommended settings